# String manipulation of cell contents in polars

Tags: python-polars

In polars, I am trying to perform selection of rows and create a new content based on string manipulation. However, the python string manipulation commands below don't work. I've seen polars uses regular expressions, but am unsure how to use this to create a number from the option_type column using everything before the '_'.

```
import polars as pl

columns = ['2022-03-01_bid', '2022-03-01_ask', 'option_type']

data = [
    [100.0, 110.0, '100_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '100_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '200_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '200_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '300_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '300_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '400_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '400_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '500_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '500_C'],
]

df = pl.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# Filter rows where option_type ends with "P"
df_filtered = df[df['option_type'].str.endswith("_P")]

# Create a new column "strike"
df_filtered['strike'] = df_filtered['option_type'].str.split("_").str[0].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    '2022-03-01_bid': [100.0, 100.0,100.0,100.0,100.0], 
    '2022-03-01_ask': [110.0, 110.0,110.0,110.0,110.0],
    'option_type' : ['100_P', '100_C', '200_P', '200_C', '300_P']
})

df_filtered = df.filter(pl.col('option_type').str.ends_with('_P'))

df_filtered = df_filtered.with_columns(
    strike = pl.col('option_type').str.split("_").arr.get(0).cast(pl.UInt32),
)
```

Outputs:

```
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬────────┐
│ 2022-03-01_bid ┆ 2022-03-01_ask ┆ option_type ┆ strike │
│ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---         ┆ ---    │
│ f64            ┆ f64            ┆ str         ┆ u32    │
╞════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════╪════════╡
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 100_P       ┆ 100    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 200_P       ┆ 200    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 300_P       ┆ 300    │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴────────┘
```

Also the square bracket masking syntax from pandas isn't really the way of polars, see this article on [coming from pandas](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html)

**EDIT**

If you wanted to use a regular expression (perhaps a slightly cleaner solution) you could do something like this

```
df_filtered = df_filtered.with_columns(
    strike = pl.col('option_type').str.extract(r"(\d+)").cast(pl.UInt32)
)
```

Comment: I find this answer simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Regex

Using the sample data you've shared, to get the new columns 'strike' as integer you can use [polars.Expr.str.extract](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.extract.html), passing your regex expression and selecting the group you intend to capture.

```
import polars as pl

columns = ['2022-03-01_bid', '2022-03-01_ask', 'option_type']

data = [
    [100.0, 110.0, '100_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '100_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '200_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '200_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '300_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '300_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '400_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '400_C'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '500_P'],
    [100.0, 110.0, '500_C'],
]

df = pl.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df.with_columns(
    [pl.col("option_type").str.extract(r"\d+", 0).cast(pl.Int64).alias("strike")]
)

shape: (10, 4)
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬────────┐
│ 2022-03-01_bid ┆ 2022-03-01_ask ┆ option_type ┆ strike │
│ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---         ┆ ---    │
│ f64            ┆ f64            ┆ str         ┆ i64    │
╞════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════╪════════╡
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 100_P       ┆ 100    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 100_C       ┆ 100    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 200_P       ┆ 200    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 200_C       ┆ 200    │
│ …              ┆ …              ┆ …           ┆ …      │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 400_P       ┆ 400    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 400_C       ┆ 400    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 500_P       ┆ 500    │
│ 100.0          ┆ 110.0          ┆ 500_C       ┆ 500    │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴────────┘
```

### Using str and arr Expressions

Another way, if you know that the structure is always the same, is to use `pl.Expr.str.split` and `pl.Expr.arr.first`. The first splits your column values and returns them as a list `["100", "P"]`, the second selects the first value of this list, in this case `"100"`.

```
df.with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("option_type")
            .str.split("_")
            .arr.first()
            .cast(pl.Int64)
            .alias("strike")
        ]
    )
```

A variation of this, for different indexes, can be used as follows, with the `arr.take()` selecting the index to return and `.explode()` exploding the results out of the list and allowing us to convert it to integers.

```
df.with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("option_type")
            .str.split("_")
            .arr.take(0)
            .explode()
            .cast(pl.Int64)
            .alias("strike")
        ]
    )
```

If there is something more complicated to parse, you can always use `pl.Expr.apply` and pass a function that makes the operations you need. However, this is [strongly discouraged in the Polars Guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html) and as shown above, for string parsing, there are good "native" alternatives.